# Scrolling only inside flexbox child

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar

I'm a CSS beginner and I'm experimenting with scrolling and flexbox. Here is my current attempt

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh; 
}

#root {
  height: 100vh; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

header, footer {
  min-height: 50px; 
  background-color:blue; 
  flex: 0 0 auto
}

#main-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

#main-panel-header {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

#main-panel-content {
  background-color: orange;  
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <header id="header">Header</header>
  <div id="main-panel">
    <div id="main-panel-header">Main Panel Header 2</div>
    <div id="main-panel-content">
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make `main-panel-content` scroll, and always keep both headers and the footer visible. Right now, the scrolling happens on the whole page, rather than my main panel content. Since the whole design is flexible, I don't want to use a fixed height for the main panel.

Any tips on how to debug such issues?

Comment: min-height:0 to #main-panel and you have a typo in overflow-y

Comment: Thank you for your help! Any pointers as to why `min-height` is necessary?

Comment: I added a duplicate

Comment: Just saw that, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can add below code to #main-panel

```
overflow-y:scroll;  
display:block;
```

You Can Find full code : https://codepen.io/chamman01/pen/poeYMwG

Hope you got your Answer

Comment: Thanks, but I want the red header to also be fixed and not scrollable. Setting min-height:0 on the main panel fixes it as suggested in the comments.